# Rails 3 class method with select("...") is giving wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, class-method

I wish to use this method like

```
@results = Candidate.all.match_against(options)
```

, where "options" is an array of integers. And it should return me all candidates with their match score.

In Candidate model I have a method for matching candidates against options given as a parameter.

```
def self.match_against(cu_options)                                           
  select("candidates.id, candidates.first_name, candidates.last_name, candidates.number, 
  sum(case when c_answers.option_id in (?) then 1 else 0 end) as score", cu_options)
  .joins("join answers as c_answers on c_answers.user_id = candidates.user_id")
  .joins("join options on c_answers.option_id = options.id")
  .where("options.ordering >= 0")
  .group("candidates.id, candidates.number, candidates.first_name, candidates.last_name")
end
```

For some reason when I'm calling this method it gives me an error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@vaalikone/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:34:in `select'
from /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@vaalikone/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/acteve_record/base.rb:442:in `select'
from /home/mika/projects/vaalikone/app/models/candidate.rb:35:in `match_against'
...
```

I have no idea where the second argument is coming from. I'm passing in only one argument. I'm using postgresql.

Comment: For those possible wondering about the same issue. I made the query to work by replacing the "(?)" with '(" + cu_options.join(',') + ")'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are passing two arguments to the select scope:

- the string "candidates.id, candidates.first_name, candidates.last_name, candidates.number, 
  sum(case when c_answers.option_id in (?) then 1 else 0 end) as score"
- the variable cu_options

Is there any reason for that?

Comment: You are right. I was hoping that second argument in the select() to go into the "?" in the first string. I have successfully used this kind of code in my controller: "Question.where('questions.id not in (?)', my_array)". This turns into "SELECT questions.* FROM questions WHERE (id not in (1,2))". Why the same wouldn't work in the select()?

Comment: Well, where takes other parameters than select ;) Basically, I would argue that there is no need to interpolate anything when using select because the database structure should be known when calling select while where could have to generate dynamic conditions based on row contents.